# Fortigate PPTP push default gateway and DNS server

Tags: vpn, fortigate

I've got a fortigate 40C here and copied the config mainly from a Fortigate60.
Everything is working fine, but I've got some problems with the PPTP VPN connection. I want to add SSL VPN in the future, but for now PPTP is fine.

At the moment I got a working configuration, but some things are not working properly.

- the DNS server is not pushed to the client. It should be 192.168.6.1 like via DHCP.
- the client should use the gateway 192.168.6.1, not 192.168.160.1

I use the OS X VPN client to connect and I've added the dns entry + network settings manually, so it works.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the DNS + Gateway pushed properly to the client?

```
   config system dns
        set primary 8.8.8.8
        set secondary 8.8.4.4
        set domain "lan"
   end
```

config firewall address
       edit "all"
       next
       edit "Internal_Range"
           set subnet 192.168.6.0 255.255.255.0
       next
       edit "PPTP"
           set associated-interface "wan1"
           set type iprange
           set end-ip 192.168.6.180
           set start-ip 192.168.6.160
       next
   end
    config firewall policy
        edit 1
            set srcintf "internal"
            set dstintf "wan1"
            set srcaddr "all"
            set dstaddr "all"
            set action accept
            set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
            set nat enable
        next
        edit 50
            set srcintf "wan1"
            set dstintf "internal"
            set srcaddr "PPTP"
            set dstaddr "all"
            set action accept
            set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
        next
        edit 4
            set srcintf "wan1"
            set dstintf "wan1"
            set srcaddr "PPTP"
            set dstaddr "all"
            set action accept
            set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
            set nat enable
        next
    end
    config vpn pptp
        set status enable
        set eip 192.168.6.180
        set sip 192.168.6.160
        set usrgrp "Wizard_users"
    end
    config system dhcp server
        edit 1
            set default-gateway 192.168.6.1
            set domain "lan"
            set interface "internal"
            config ip-range
                edit 1
                    set end-ip 192.168.6.159
                    set start-ip 192.168.6.100
                next
            end
            set lease-time 345600
            set netmask 255.255.255.0
            set dns-server1 192.168.6.1
        next
    end
    config system interface
    edit "wan1"
        set vdom "root"
        set mode pppoe
        set allowaccess ping
        set type physical
        set alias "FTTB Fixed IP"
        set username "X@X"
        set password ENC X
        set defaultgw enable
        set dns-server-override disable
    next
    edit "modem"
        set vdom "root"
        set mode pppoe
        set type physical
    next
    edit "ssl.root"
        set vdom "root"
        set type tunnel
    next
    edit "internal"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.6.1 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh
        set type physical
        set alias "LAN"
    next
end

edit: The DNS server, the gateway are all on the Fortigate unit with the IP 192.168.6.1.

Comment: `192.168.16.1` is the gateway, the DNS server, and the IP of the internal interface for clients to use? Is your client receiving the DNS server config via DHCP (please verify)? Sorry I missed this, where is your DNS server? If it's the Fortigate's DNS server daemon, you might need to take some internal routing steps on the Fortigate.

Comment: @mbrownnyc DNS server is 192.168.6.1(the fortigate). the internal network is 192.168.6.1/24 and the VPN network is in the range 192.168.6.160-180

Comment: @mbrownnyc yeah, I added the DNS and search domain to the client,so that's fine. My main problem is that I don't get the gateway when I use the VPN as default connection. I can connect to the internal network just fine, however accessing external addresses doesn't work and I really have no idea what to change in the configuration to make it work nor can I find some documentation for that.

Comment: Can you confirm that the DNS server address is assigned to the client(s) as expected?  Also look at the [(old) VPN guide](http://pub.kb.fortinet.com/ksmcontent/Fortinet-Public/current/Fortigate_v3.0/FortiGate_PPTP_VPN_User_Guide_01-30005-0349-20070926.pdf).  Also, try [debugging packet flow](http://mbrownnyc.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/fortigate-debugging-on-a-fortigate/).  You might need to handle internal routing (incoming WAN1 PPTP => Internal DNS server), but I can not find the commands to do so.

Comment: @mbrownnyc I saw that guide, but I can just find how to connect to the internal network, not how to get a working gateway over the VPN connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now. I didn't see the NAT checkbox :(

```
edit 50
        set srcintf "wan1"
        set dstintf "internal"
            set srcaddr "PPTP"
            set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
        set nat enable
    next
```

To the other part @mbrownnyc is right. The fortigate can't push the DNS server, Gateway or search domain.